# Unexpected Error while installing MySQL 8 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I want to install MySQL-8 on Ubuntu-16.04 and I am following official documentation. I haven't installed MySQL on this server in past so this one is the first installation of MySQL.

First, I've downloaded mysql-apt-config using `wget` just like this:

`root@test-server:~# wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb`

Then, I updated repositories using `sudo apt-get update` and then I configured mysql-community-server using `dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb` and selected the version I want to install (mysql-8).

Then I tried to install MySQL server using `apt` just like this:

`root@test-server:~# sudo apt-get install mysql-server -y`

It asked me for root password and I entered it but then, It is showing me following error.

```
.
.
Setting up mysql-community-server-core (8.0.11-1ubuntu17.10) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.11-1ubuntu17.10) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.11-1ubuntu17.10); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for systemd (234-2ubuntu12.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-20) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It says that `mysql-community-server` isn't configured but I already configured it before. I tried re-installing operating system multiple time and also tried installing MySQL 8 using different methods but it's throwing me the same error every time.

Comment: You might read this Ask Ubuntu [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221522/meaning-of-processing-triggers-for-ureadahead).